# Proper way of handling login of users that use just a code to Firebase

Tags: firebase-authentication

I need to create a mobile app in which guests will use just the code for their authentication, which is valid for dedicated period of time, so they can apply for different activities in the hotel.

What would be the **"proper"** way of login those users in Firebase?

Note: I have "real" users as well in Firebase.

Comment: So would you like to implement an anonymous authentication and only use a generated code?

Comment: Yeah, I guess. Is that a viable option?

Comment: Have you tried [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth)? Try it and tell us if it works.

Comment: I'll try and let you know. Thanks.